# How to add try exception in scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I build a simple crawler application by using urllib2 and beautifulsoup, now i am planning to change it into scrapy spider, but how i can handle errors while running crawler,
My current application have some code like this,

```
error_file = open('errors.txt','a')
finish_file = open('finishlink.txt','a')
try:
    #Code for process each links
    #if sucessfully finished link store into 'finish.txt' file
except Exception as e:
    #link write into 'errors.txt' file with error code
```

so when i am processing thousands of links, the successfully processed links will store into finish.txt and error's will be in errors.txt, so i can run links in errors later until successfully processed.
So how i can accomplish these in these code,

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open('filename+'.txt', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [spider middleware](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#spider-middleware) and override the [`process_spider_exception()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_exception) method, saving the links in a file there.

A spider middleware is just a way for you to extend Scrapy's behavior.
Here is a full example that you can modify as needed for your purpose:

```
from scrapy import signals


class SaveErrorsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, crawler):
        crawler.signals.connect(self.close_spider, signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(self.open_spider, signals.spider_opened)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.output_file = open('somefile.txt', 'a')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.output_file.close()

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        self.output_file.write(response.url + '\n')
```

Put this in a module and set it up in settings.py:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middleware.SaveErrorsMiddleware': 1000,
}
```

This code will run together with your spider, triggering the open_spider(), close_spider(), process_spider_exception() methods when appropriated.

**Read more:**

- [Spider Middlewares](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#spider-middleware)
- [Signals in Scrapy](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html)
- [Example middleware in Scrapy source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/httperror.py)

Comment: In which file i can add this function `process_spider_exception()`, in `spider.py` or any other file. if you explain more with some code it will be very helpful, because i just start scrapy from yesterday onwards and can't find any other examples in internet ...

Comment: @Jake okay, I added a complete example -- this should get you going. =)